# How to implement alert dialog box?

Tags: android

I've a button which if clicked opens a alert dialog box with list of call logs. But only dialog box title is displayed on doing so.. Here is my code:

```
 protected void showCustomDialog() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // this method returns the cursor with all call logs.. i've checked the cursor                                 and it is returning.
            Cursor curLog = CallLogHelper.getAllCallLogs(getContentResolver());

            // it fills the conNames arraylist with its values.
            setCallLogs(curLog);

            ListView listitems=new ListView(this);
            MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter( this , R.layout.dialog_list,conNames);

            //dialog_list is layout of each item of the list.

            alertDialogStores = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setView(listitems)
            .setTitle("Stores")
            .show();
}
```

Comment: yes since ur code says only to display title what u r exceptiona lert to do? i mean any buttons?

Comment: i'm expecting the list of call logs. Do u want to see some other code?

Comment: what does setCallLogs do? give u string?

Comment: its fills the arraylist conNames with the call logs returned from getAllCallLogs

Comment: and conNames u wanna display as log ?

Comment: look my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

```
listitems.setAdapter(adapter);
```

after

```
ListView listitems=new ListView(this);
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter( this , R.layout.dialog_list,conNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use below code for ur logs to be displayed :

use below code for forming string from arraylist something like this :

```
String msg="";
for(int i=0;i<conNames.size();i++)
{msg=msg+" "+conNames;}

  alertDialogStores = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setView(listitems)
            .setTitle("Stores")
            .show();
            .setMessage("my logs"+msg);
```